# Bootstrap - carousel - Remove additional space

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) I have a carousel as follows:

```
<!-- TEST carousel --> 
<div id="TESTcarousel" class="hero-unit carousel slide"> 
    <div class="carousel-inner"> 
        <div class="item active"> 
            .........
        </div> 
        <div class="item"> 
            .........
        </div> 
        <div class="item"> 
            .........
        </div> 
    </div><!-- .carousel-inner --> 

<!--  next and previous controls here 
          href values must reference the id for this carousel --> 
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#TESTcarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a> 
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#TESTcarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a> 
</div><!-- .carousel -->
```

It renders as:

[image: Example render]

I'd like to remove some of the additional space in the purple area, the padding. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which carousel you are using ?

Comment: @dhana http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `hero-class` because this is the one that is adding the paddings.

In the latest carousel (and in the old one if I'm not mistaken) there is no much padding actually and it looks like you're using Bootstrap 2.

Comment: I've downloaded and upgraded to the latest release of bootstrap, the style of my site has changed completley, the carousel has no features at all (no nav buttons, background styling), the Navbar has changed to what looks like a smartphone interface.

Comment: It is not a simple update.. you have to go through and update a looot of things.. http://getbootstrap.com/migration/